# Query that simply checks pg_stats returns error

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

So its a simple question and only experienced users can answer this question, Why is the following query able to run?

```
SELECT attname, inherited, n_distinct, 
    array_to_string(most_common_vals, E'\n') as most_common_vals
FROM pg_stats
WHERE tablename = 'person';
```

This query works perfectly fine

But when i run this query

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_stats
WHERE tablename = 'person';
```

***I get the follow error:*** 
No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111

Comment: Which client are you using to run this query? I think a column that's being returned isn't being properly translated by your client

Comment: do you mean if im using postgres 9.3 ?

Comment: no, if you're using psql, pgAdmin, etc to connect to Postgres. If you used those tools JDBC should not have come up.

Comment: i will get back to you!